# Reading line from website

Tags: java, android

I am making a little program thath will read data from website. String in the html file is already managed every info is divided with ; . Now i should read complete line here is example of this line:

```
14:47;24.02.12;18.7°C;18.7°C;285;0.5m/s; 6:48;17:37; Warm ;36;1.8;0.0;
```

So first how should i read them with HTTP Get or is there anything other? And then i would like to save each info, they are seperated with ; into a variable. And how should i cut each info from this line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely need to do some homework, but this methods will help you:

```
public static String getContentFromUrl(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;

    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {

        InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();

        String result = HttpService.convertStreamToString(inStream);
        inStream.close();

        return result;
    }

    return null;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This allows you to get data from a URL. Then lookup String.split to chop your string into usable entities.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks for this, but one question why do you use String result = HttpService.convertStreamToString(inStream); as convertStreamToString is method not part of Httpservice?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that. HttpService is actually the name of the class I created, not the android one. I should definitely rename my class.

Comment: So i should need one more class for this HttpService?

Comment: Nope the convertStreamToString() method is included in my answer. You can use it in your own class, just make sure to change HttpService.convertStreamToString() to reflect your own framework. YourClassName..convertStreamToString()

Answer (score 1):

1. Use GET request to fetch the data from the website
2. Separate the string-data from the HTML-markup
3. Parse the string into multiple strings or a list of strings, using ';' as the delimiter.

[Android Java SDK String reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: There is not HTML-Markup. Its only line of text all is inside body.

Comment: @HyperX well that makes it even easier for you :) You can parse the response body without making any modifications.